# Is there a way to add an outline to a shape in x3dom

Tags: javascript, x3d, x3dom

I just want to put an outline on a box I am hovering over. I remember seeing a tutorial on this before but now I can't seem to find anything on it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no outline attribute for a 3d shape in x3d.
You could maybe do a trick by having two boxes, the second one (the bigger one, maybe different color) being the "outline" of the first one. I would put the two in a Switch node. On mouse over display the bigger one.

Or maybe another solution (easier) is to change the size parameter of your box. You can do this by routing a SFVec3f value to the scale of your box or by writing a bit of javascript code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Currently I have it so that the box changes color on hover over but i thought it might be nice to preserve the original color while being able to indicate which box is moused over. I thought I recall looking at an example of this but maybe it was a different library.